# Some (long?) strings in one line of concatenation(s) don't work in Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

See [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65680/testing-concatenation) which works as is, but if you edit it to delete either embedded new line (or both) the query fails with:

```
Incorrect syntax near '0'.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Data Explorer currently does some pretty light (but terribly messy) mangling of your query on the backend for the purposes of extracting query parameters and removing purely cosmetic newlines.

Ignoring everything else that's wrong with the responsible code (which I've made another note to revisit in the near future), part of the routine is extracting quoted content and then re-substituting it back in....mistakenly in forward order, which makes it susceptible to token misidentification (i.e. `Token1` being swapped in for `Token10`, leaving the trailing `0`).

Iterating backwards would have been the smart thing to do there, so now [that's what happens](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=a3b31212335a984850717ae4f779b075a0d42e5d).

Comment: Tests? TESTS? This isn't the Stack Exchange I know and love

Comment: I doubt anyone at Stack Exchange would write code quite as ugly as that query parser is...so I need something to verify against when I refactor. ;)

Comment: You've not seen my code, which is why we'll never be open-source :) Nice fix you made here.

Comment: Hahah, @Jarrod :) And thanks - Should probably look into better token values too, just in case...but there's an extremely low chance anyone will accidentally provide breaking input before I get a chance to try and rework that parser code, so it can wait for now.